# Using fonts that don't support asian languages

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts, asianfonts

I'm considering using the [open-sans font](https://typekit.com/fonts/open-sans) for a cordova application that runs on Ipad and browsers. At the bottom right they mention supported languages and they don't seem to support asian languages.

I was wondering what would happen if i use that font with an asian language? would it default to a different font or would it not display properly?

On my system it renders properly, but is it because I might have some other font that supports asian lang?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware only blank squares would be displayed due to the lack of support. It might be worth using a Unicode font that provides support for multiple languages